# Export comments from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, comments

I used the following formula to export the comments from Google Sheets:

```
function myFunction() {
const excludeSheetNames = ['START', 'MASTER', 'REPORT']; // Exclude sheet names.

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const sheett = sheets.find(s => !excludeSheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
const [head, , , ...rows] = sheett.getRange("A1:A" + sheett.getLastRow()).getValues();
const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ss.getId()).getComments();
res.forEach(({ sheetName, comments }, h) => {
sheetName = sheets[h].getSheetName();
if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
  head.push(sheetName);
  rows.forEach((e, i) => {
    const t = comments.find(f => i == f.range.row - 4);
    e.push(t ? t.comment[0].comment.trim() : null);
  });
}
});
const values = [head, ...rows];
const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("REPORT") || ss.insertSheet("REPORT");
dstSheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

to create inside the same Google spreadsheet a REPORT out of them.

When I run the script I get the following errors:

```
9:50:13 AM  Error   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setName')
(anonymous)         @ ExcelApp.gs:408
getImagesAsObject   @ ExcelApp.gs:379
(anonymous)         @ ExcelApp.gs:39
getAll              @ ExcelApp.gs:34
getComments         @ SpreadsheetAppp.gs:49
myFunction          @ REPORT.gs:8
```

[image: execution log]

I am sharing the Google Sheet file with the script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GRNbQevnleNTvWDPm8Pg1veBFm4_an6g5qvqL-SeGK4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize. When I tested your showing script using your provided Spreadsheet, I could notice that when the inserted image has no binary data, such an error occurs. From this situation, I updated the library and modified your showing script. Please confirm it. When I tested the modified script with the updated library, I confirmed that no error occurred and the comments were retrieved.

Comment: @Tanaike Everything is working. Thank you once more, Mr. Tanaike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested the script using your provided Spreadsheet. I confirmed the following modification points.

- When the inserted image in the Spreadsheet has no binary data, an error occurs. This is the reason for your showing an error message.

  - This issue was on the library side. I updated the library to remove this issue.
- As the next issue, when a comment was removed, an error occurs at `e.push(t ? t.comment[0].comment.trim() : null);` in the script.

  - This issue was removed by the following modified script.

#### Modified script:

I updated the library. So, **please reinstall the library and test it again**.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const excludeSheetNames = ['START', 'MASTER', 'REPORT']; // Exclude sheet names.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const sheett = sheets.find(s => !excludeSheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  const [head, , , ...rows] = sheett.getRange("A1:A" + sheett.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ss.getId()).getComments();
  res.forEach(({ sheetName, comments }, h) => {
    sheetName = sheets[h].getSheetName();
    if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      head.push(sheetName);
      rows.forEach((e, i) => {
        const t = comments.find(f => i == f.range.row - 4);
        ee.push((t && t.comment && t.comment.length > 0 && t.comment[0].comment) ? t.comment[0].comment.trim() : null); // Modified
      });
    }
  });
  const values = [head, ...rows.filter(([, ...r]) => r.some(c => c))]; // or const values = [head, ...rows]; // Modified
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("REPORT") || dstSS.insertSheet("REPORT");
  dstSheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When I tested this modified script using the updated library, the comments were retrieved without errors.
- Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `is it possible to retrieve the rows that only contain comments instead of the full list?`, I reflected it in the above script. When you want all rows, please use `const values = [head, ...rows];`.

#### Reference:

- [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

Comment: It is working correctly but is it possible to retrieve the rows that only contain comments instead of the full list?
If not, I am OK with this solution.

Comment: I tested to another file and returned the following errorsQ
2:48:02 PM Notice Execution started
2:48:46 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comment')
(anonymous) @ REPORT.gs:15
(anonymous) @ REPORT.gs:13
myFunction @ REPORT.gs:9

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. From `It is working correctly`, I confirmed that the script worked. About `s it possible to retrieve the rows that only contain comments instead of the full list`, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the details of it? About your new issue, this is your provided Spreadsheet. But, how about modifying `e.push(t ? t.comment[0]?.comment.trim() : null);` to `e.push((t && t.comment && t.comment.length > 0 && t.comment[0].comment) ? t.comment[0].comment.trim() : null);`?

Comment: @dek Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Mr. Tanaike thank you for your reply.
There is an error in the formula line 15 "ee.push((t && t.comment && t.comment.length > 0 && t.comment[0].comment) ? t.comment[0].comment.trim() : null); // Modified" that has double 'e' . 
Also, the script includes the sheet tabs with no comments inside like 21/12 on the sample file. Can we change that? If not no problem. Thank you again very much!

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. About your new issue, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurred. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information for correctly replicating your new issue? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution.

Comment: Mr Tanaike there is no error in the formula. The formula works just fine. A minor trimming needs only. I will post a new question. Thank you for your support!

Comment: @dek Thank you for replying. I understand that no error occurs. About `A minor trimming needs only`, when I saw your new question and could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Mr. Tanaike hi,
Is there any issue with the library I am using from you? Today I am getting error 500 when I open Apps Script in Google sheet.

Comment: @dek I guessed that your situation might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78060477 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326802543

Comment: Mr. Tanaike, once again you were right and wrong. The links you gave me described the situation exactly. The problem was fixed after a few hours.
Who would have thought that this could happen from Google
Thank you for your support.