# Apps Script is not working for 3 hours already

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Need info about this incident, because there are many things that are dead now. This has never happened before and nothing appears to be working. I get a 500 or 506 error which say that the issue is an "internal server error". Is there are any way to make it work? And in which regions this issue is also appearing?
*UPD works again

Answer (score 3):

Yes and we can monitor these two place:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community?pli=1

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B&pli=1

Everyone is talking about it but we can only wait for Google to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any way around the issue until Google fixes it.  As you can see from Google's Issue Tracker in the link shared by darrelltw (Updated link as the issues have now been consolidated:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326802543), it has been impacting users in many places around the world.

In the interest of adding some more information (as many people are trying to get answers), I am including the following link providing Google's confirmation of the issue here:  https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status?product=WORKSPACE.

Screenshot from the above site:

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**

Here in my region of the USA, my Apps Script projects are now currently accessible for the first time this morning.  But this is apparently not universal because the upvotes on Google's Issue Tracker continue to increase.