# 503 error in google apps script sidebar and modal

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am having issues loading HTML into a modal window or sidebar in Google Sheets. I have tried starting a fresh project and I can instantly recreate the issue. Here is the *entire* code

```
function myFunction() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Hello, sidebar!</p>');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

This results in 2 errors in the console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)` and `Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for'` and the following image shows the sidebar

[image]

I have tried multiple browsers, creating a new spreadsheet and clearing cache and cookies. Google also prompts for permission the first time I tried to run it and I allowed that. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue as this question:
[Apps Script is not working for 3 hours already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78060477/apps-script-is-not-working-for-3-hours-already) posted earlier this morning.

**Situation:**

There does not appear to be any way around the issue until Google fixes it.  As you can see from Google's Issue Tracker in the following link:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326802543), it has been impacting users in many places around the world.

In the interest of adding some more information (as many people are trying to get answers), I am including the following link providing Google's confirmation of the issue here:  https://support.cloud.google.com/portal/system-status?product=WORKSPACE.

Screenshot from the above site:

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**

Here in my region of the USA, my Apps Script projects are now currently accessible for the first time this morning.  But this is apparently not universal because the upvotes on Google's Issue Tracker continue to increase.

Comment: You are correct, I was just impatient. Working in Australia now